# Could I just close(cheat) the video card output for energy saving?

Tags: graphics-card

I'm playing a game, just hanging it up waiting for a task to finish. So I want to know if I could close the video output to save energy, because I don't care about the game video output.
ENV: Windows with NVIDIA video card.

---

edited:
I mean, could I "hook" some api to cheat the game not really doing 3d rendering to save energy, because I just want to hang the game up, not really playing.

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking. You're playing a game but don't care about the game video output? You need more detail or a better worded question.

Comment: If you 'close' the video output, your monitor/tv will turn into sleep mode, so you will save the energy of the monitor...

Comment: @DrZoo sorry for my bad english, I mean could I "cheat" the game client, not rendering 3d scene, just leave it there to hang up to save energy.

Comment: @Flowersun, it's not certain that it would work, for all games, for all video cards, etc.  There's two ways I can think of to determine if there are electrical savings.  1) Turn on temperature graphing program for the video card,  have it record during play/during pause , and compare.  2)  Purchase an electrical meter like a Kill-A-Watt , and watch your PC's consumption during the different phases.

Comment: To explain about the temperature monitor : If more heat is being produced, then more electricity is being used.

Comment: Assuming the game has a proper incremental render (IE, it doesn't re-render if the scene isn't changing), you can adjust the view in-game so that nothing on screen is changing at all, and probably achieve the desired effect without needing to 'cheat'.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not really. See the problem with graphics cards is: 
1. they use a lot of energy even when idling. 
2. its not really optional to render things in games.

Now with that said, here are some things I can think of to help with energy consumption

1. Turn down the settings in the game to minimum in the game you are rendering. The less work your graphics card is doing, the less energy your graphics card will pull.
2. Set your nvidia settings for this specific application to target your integrated graphics. This will probably have the largest effect.
3. Set your nvidia settings to have a max FPS that it is willing to render.
4. Undervolting/underclocking your GPU. This wont save a lot of energy, but it will save some. Generally though, it isn't worth it to this end.

However, if you were really sold on doing what you describe, you would have to write your own fake opengl driver (assuming the game uses opengl) and just not render anything. Also, you could modify the binary game file to run a noop instruction anywhere it calls the graphics library code. However, with obstification in games today this is essentially infeasible.